# Getting the count of uniqe observations in a particular column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that has a column containing multiple-choice responses. The column has this structure

```
Improvement <- c("Solarisation, Storage expansion, pipeline extension, other",
                 "pipeline extension", "Solarisation, Treatment", "Treatmemt, Other", "pipeline extension, treatment")
Multiple <- data.frame(Improvement)
```

I want to get the count of unique observations present in the column Improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You may try(base `R`)

```
table(unlist(sapply(Multiple$Improvement, function(x) strsplit(x, ", "))))

     other              Other pipeline extension       Solarisation  Storage expansion          Treatmemt 
         1                  1                  3                  2                  1                  1 
 treatment          Treatment 
         1                  1
```

Thanks to @Sotos

```
table(unlist(strsplit(Multiple$Improvement, ", ")))
```

Comment: FYI, `strsplit` is vectorised, so simply `table(unlist(strsplit(Multiple$Improvement, ', ')))` will suffice

Comment: @Sotos Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `separate_rows()`, i.e.

```
table(tidyr::separate_rows(Multiple, Improvement) )

   expansion    extension        other        Other     pipeline Solarisation      Storage    Treatmemt    treatment    Treatment 
           1            3            1            1            3            2            1            1            1            1
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated to include tolower to avoid counting things twice

```
 Multiple %>% 
 separate(Improvement, c("A", "B", "C", "D"), sep = ",") %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(c("A", "B", "C", "D")), funs(tolower(.))) %>% 
 gather()  %>% 
 count(value)
```